# Why in this IF function, does Asterix (*) work but the AND function does not?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array function which looks at a sheet labelled Bike, and pulls through their Employee ID IF they do NOT have a Leave Date and also IF their Annual Amount is not Zero.

https://image.ibb.co/eTFooR/001.jpg

https://image.ibb.co/gzqUTR/002.jpg

My question is, that I first tried to code this with an IF(AND( formula but it did not work however it does work with an Asterix (*) in between the conditions.

Here is the formula that is working:

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((Bike!$D$2:$D$14="")*(Bike!$C$2:$C$14<>0),Bike!$B$2:$B$14,""),ROW()-1),"")}
```

Here is the formula that doesn't:

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(AND((Bike!$D$2:$D$14=""),(Bike!$C$2:$C$14<>0)),Bike!$B$2:$B$14,""),ROW()-1),"")}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` only returns a single result, so this part

`=AND((Bike!$D$2:$D$14=""),(Bike!$C$2:$C$14<>0))`

will return just `TRUE` if all 26 cells meet the criteria - `FALSE` otherwise

whereas with

`=(Bike!$D$2:$D$14="")*(Bike!$C$2:$C$14<>0)`

That returns an array of 13 values, 1 when both conditions are `TRUE` for that row, 0 otherwise, e.g. `{0;0;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;1}`

Because of the above `AND` cannot be used **reliably** in these sort of array formulas (and nor can `OR` because that also returns a single result). You will get a result (not an error)....but probably not the correct one

You can see this for yourself by putting either of the above in a cell and then pressing `F2` then `F9` to see the result generated